# Vite builds locally; Deploying to heroku timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, vite

We have a react app that we were building using webpack, but are trying to migrate into Vite the significantly lower build times.

We've successfully refactored our build code to use vite, where builds and dev server run successfully when we run them locally. However, whenever we deploy to heroku, and the build script starts... the build simply stalls on the while transforming the js files.

Log Below:

```
...
2023-02-05T19:26:35.377Z vite:resolve 2.32ms css_variables/colors.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/css_variables/colors.css
2023-02-05T19:26:35.861Z vite:resolve 0.33ms css_variables/durations.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/css_variables/durations.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.059Z vite:resolve 0.12ms css_variables/sizes.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/css_variables/sizes.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.090Z vite:resolve 0.12ms css_variables/indices.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/css_variables/indices.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.175Z vite:resolve 0.22ms index.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/index.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.210Z vite:resolve 0.12ms nav_bar.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/nav_bar.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.340Z vite:resolve 0.19ms other_pages/auth_page.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/other_pages/auth_page.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.460Z vite:resolve 0.37ms other_pages/page.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/other_pages/page.css
2023-02-05T19:26:36.724Z vite:resolve 0.19ms other_pages/simple_pages.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/other_pages/simple_pages.css
2023-02-05T19:26:37.009Z vite:resolve 0.18ms superadmin/superadmin_page.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/superadmin/superadmin_page.css
2023-02-05T19:26:37.133Z vite:resolve 0.16ms other_pages/pricing_calculator_page.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/other_pages/pricing_calculator_page.css
2023-02-05T19:26:37.954Z vite:resolve 0.20ms other_pages/project_portfolio_page.css -> /tmp/build_38ed17db/src/css/other_pages/project_portfolio_page.css
```

I've been scratching my head for days, because there are no log outputs for an error having occurred, and I've run out of options for searching online for solutions to this problem.

Our config looks as follows:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-polyfill-node";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import progress from 'vite-plugin-progress'
import dns from "dns";

dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, ssrBuild }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");

  return {
    base: "/",
    root: "./",

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "react-native": "react-native-web",
        "src": path.resolve(path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), "./src"),
        util: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
        sys: "util",
        events: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events",
        stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
        path: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path",
        querystring: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs",
        punycode: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode",
        url: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url",
        string_decoder:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder",
        http: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
        https: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
        os: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os",
        assert: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert",
        constants: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants",
        _stream_duplex:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex",
        _stream_passthrough:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough",
        _stream_readable:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable",
        _stream_writable:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable",
        _stream_transform:
          "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform",
        timers: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers",
        console: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console",
        vm: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm",
        zlib: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib",
        tty: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty",
        domain: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain",
        buffer: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/buffer-es6",
        process: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6",
        "node-modules-polyfills:buffer": "buffer",
        "node-modules-polyfills:string_decoder": "string_decoder"
      }
    },

    server: {
      port: 3001
    },

    // Env vars aren't exposed by default so we need to opt-in by prefix
    envPrefix: [
      "REACT_APP_",
      "NODE_ENV"
    ],

    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: env.APP_ENV,
      "process.env": env,
      VITE: true
    },

    build: {
      target: "modules",
      minify: "esbuild",
      manifest: true,
      sourcemap: true,
      outDir: "build",
      rollupOptions: {
        cache: true,
        plugins: [
          inject({
            exclude: ["node_modules/library/**/*.js"]
          }),
          rollupNodePolyFill()
        ],
        output: {
          manualChunks(id) {
            if (id.includes('recharts')) {
              return 'recharts';
            }
          }
        }
      },
      commonjsOptions: {
        transformMixedEsModules: true,
        esmExternals: "auto"
      }
    },

    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        define: {
          global: "globalThis"
        },
        plugins: [
          NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin()
        ]
      }
    },

    plugins: [
      react(),
      svgr(),
      progress()
    ]
  };
});
```

Our heroku server sets `YARN_PRODUCTION` to `true`, and uses the `YARN_CACHE` but we've attempted removing those to no avail.

I've followed just about every guide to fix this problem I can find online, and it still just wont work.

I'm under the impression that perhaps the build is running out of memory (our application is quite large), but usually when that is the case, heroku would notify us in the logs.

If there is any significant details that would be helpful in attempting to help, please let me know, and I'll do my best to provide them. But I am seriously confused at what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that heroku is running `vite build` instead of `vite dev` or something?

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure. The vite dev has a completely different output. Also, given we've changed our build script a couple times, we've seen those changes reflected in the logs, so i'm pretty confident that the build script is the script which is running.

Comment: Are you deploying directly from the console, or do you have automatic deploy configured with each push to a repository?

Comment: the latter. We merge our code to our master branch, and CI deploys it to heroku. When it reaches heroku, it runs the build script. \

Comment: I think an out of memory error would log something more specific, as you said, such as  the logs seen here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433 

Have you tried clearing the build cache on Heroku? Do the logs eventually say anything about an error or do they just hang?

Comment: it just hangs... it never produces an output that logs any exception of any kind. I've tried clearing the cache, which seems to do better (looks to get a bit further in the build), but it still always eventually hangs and times out. This is why i assumed it might be a memory issue. Although, I am aware of the logs that heroku will usually log given a out of memory exception, I cant think of what else could possibly be happening.

Comment: Do you have your code on Github? I solved my issue by switching Heroku to containers and building on Github and pushing the image to Heroku. See my repo here: https://github.com/jonshipman/heroku-github-sveltekit-files

Answer (score 0):

some tips :

this line is only relevant for dev mode server , try to comment it
dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

I think the process try to apply polyfills to existing polyfills....

Answer (score 0):

Interesting you get the logs, I just get a crash and the generic "refs failed" git error.

I contacted Heroku support and builds are limited to 2.5GB of memory. Unfortunately rollup has a "bug" where the official answer is to set max-old-space-size to 8GB. @see https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-javascript-heap-out-of-memory

I don't have an answer except to watch this space: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433

Edit: I managed to build using GitHub actions. Switch Heroku to a container stack and deploy to it using a GitHub action. I have the files here where I went more indepth: https://github.com/jonshipman/heroku-github-sveltekit-files

1. Set Heroku to a container stack. `heroku stack:set container --app <<app-name>>`
2. Create a Github Action. Add a `.github/workflows/deploy.yaml` following Github's documentation here: https://github.com/features/actions. There is a workflow called `gonuit/heroku-docker-deploy` which has built-in support for deploying images to Heroku.
3. Create a Dockerfile that can run your Sveltekit application. I use `node:18-bullseye-slim` as a base image and `COPY . .` everything to the image. I'd recommend `.dockerignore`'ing the standard `.gitignore` files. In your Dockerfile, install and build the application. You can remove the node_modules and .svelte-kit folders after `npm run build`. That will reduce the file size as `adapter-node` bundles all deps within the build folder.
4. Ensure the CMD is set to what will run your application - something like `node build/index.js` will work.

That should do it. It requires using Github as a middleware to push, but better than not being able to deploy I say.

Comment: hm this seems a bit more like commentary than an answer. answer posts are for answers.

Comment: Then the answer is "watch vite issue 2433 until someone solves it" or "fork, fix it yourself, and issue a PR".